# ZSH and VSCode - Default Shells (Pop!_OS)

Tags: shell, zsh, visual-studio-code

**O.S: Pop!_OS**

ZSH didn't display in the list of shell options.

When I run `which zsh` returns `/usr/bin/zsh`, so I added `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "usr/bin/zsh"`  to vscode settings, but this doesn't work to. I also tried using `/bin/zsh`.

Error when I try open terminal:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/usr/bin/zsh" does not exist.
```

Comment: I realized that I installed VS Code with flatpak instead of deb in the Pop!_Shop

Comment: I did the same thing. That also explains why terminal -> code . didn't work